# Create a list of string from a .txt file

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create a list of string reading the words from a .txt files. My code only works when the .txt files contains a small amount of words and i can't figure out why, I think it's a problem of memory allocation of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> struct s_nodo {
    char* word;
    struct s_nodo*sig; }; typedef struct s_nodo* t_nodo;

void add (t_nodo*,char*); void print(t_nodo);

int main() {
    char aux[30];
    t_nodo lista=NULL;
    FILE*fd;
    fd=fopen("c:\\texto.txt","r");
    while(!feof(fd))
    {
        fscanf(fd,"%s",aux);
        add(&lista,aux);

    }
     print(lista);
    return 0; }



void add (t_nodo*lista,char *aux) {

    if(*lista==NULL)
    {
        *lista=malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
        (*lista)->word=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy((*lista)->word,aux);
        (*lista)->sig=NULL;

    }
    else add (&(*lista)->sig,aux);

}

void print (t_nodo lista) {
    if(lista!=NULL)
    {
        printf("-%s-",lista->word);
        print(lista->sig);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coding style leads to this mistake right here

```
(*lista)->word=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char));
                        //       ^
```

1. Don't use `sizeof(char)` because it's 1 and that's mandatory, it just helped you overlook this problem.
2. Use more white space, that will separate tokens easily before your eyes.
3. Always check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL` before using the pointer.

So it should be

```
(*lista)->word = malloc(strlen(aux) + 1);
```

see how it's clear now, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, now it's working, but i don't understand why i shouldn't put sizeof(char), can you explain me?

Comment: Because it's 1. You don't need to and doing it just makes the code hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating memory for the size of pointer-to structure, whereas you need to allocate memory for the size of the structure itself.

Change

```
  *lista=malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
```

to

```
  *lista=malloc(sizeof(struct s_nodo));
```

Also, you're using wrong expression to allocate memory to `word`.

```
(*lista)->word=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
(*lista)->word=malloc( (strlen(aux) + 1 );  //sizeof(char) == 1 in C
```

That said, please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)